# foreach title in array php

Tags: php, html, css

I need to show 3 different titles from array in div. How can I do it? I have variable $str - I am trying to show $title from $articles but actually it's just showing $str 3 times. Varible $title is in

```
<?php
$articles = array(
    array(
        "title" => "Featured title 1",
        "description" => "Paragraph of text beneath the heading to explain the heading. We'll add onto it with another sentence and probably just keep going until we run out of words.",
        "link" => "page1.php",
    ),
    array(
        "title" => "Featured title 2",
        "description" => "Paragraph of text beneath the heading to explain the heading. We'll add onto it with another sentence and probably just keep going until we run out of words.",
        "link" => "page2.php",
    ),
    array(
        "title" => "Featured title 3",
        "description" => "Paragraph of text beneath the heading to explain the heading. We'll add onto it with another sentence and probably just keep going until we run out of words.",
        "link" => "page2.php",
    ),
);

$title = 'Paragraph of text';

$str = '
            <div class="feature col">
                <div class="feature-icon bg-primary bg-gradient">
                    <svg class="bi" width="1em" height="1em"><use xlink:href="#collection"></use></svg>
                </div>
                <h2>'.$title.'</h2>
                <p>Paragraph of text beneath the heading to explain the heading. We\'ll add onto it with another sentence and probably just keep going until we run out of words.</p>
                <a href="#" class="icon-link">
                    Call to action
                    <svg class="bi" width="1em" height="1em"><use xlink:href="#chevron-right"></use></svg>
                </a>
            </div>
            ';
foreach ($articles as $v){
    echo $str;
    }
```

Comment: you want to move your "$str = ...." within your loop and put
`$title = $v['title'];`
above.

Answer (score 0):

you need to load the `$title` variable from the looped array

```
$articles = array(
    array(
        "title" => "Featured title 1",
        "description" => "Paragraph of text beneath the heading to explain the heading. We'll add onto it with another sentence and probably just keep going until we run out of words.",
        "link" => "page1.php",
    ),
    array(
        "title" => "Featured title 2",
        "description" => "Paragraph of text beneath the heading to explain the heading. We'll add onto it with another sentence and probably just keep going until we run out of words.",
        "link" => "page2.php",
    ),
    array(
        "title" => "Featured title 3",
        "description" => "Paragraph of text beneath the heading to explain the heading. We'll add onto it with another sentence and probably just keep going until we run out of words.",
        "link" => "page2.php",
    ),
);

$title = 'Paragraph of text';

$str = '<div class="feature col">
            <div class="feature-icon bg-primary bg-gradient">
                <svg class="bi" width="1em" height="1em"><use xlink:href="#collection"></use></svg>
            </div>
            <h2>'.$title.'</h2>
            <p>Paragraph of text beneath the heading to explain the heading. We\'ll add onto it with another sentence and probably just keep going until we run out of words.</p>
            <a href="#" class="icon-link">
                Call to action
                <svg class="bi" width="1em" height="1em">
                    <use xlink:href="#chevron-right"></use>
                </svg>
            </a>
        </div>';

foreach ($articles as $v){
    $title = $var['title'];
    echo $str;
}
```